# PHP & Array question

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called $array_all;

This array will always have 3 possible values:

- 1,
- 1,2,
- 1,2,3,

I created a string from the array while in a foreach loop and concatenated a comma at the end.

So, now I have a nice string that outputs the exact value the way it should.

**1,2,3,** I can copy this output from my browser and insert it into my wordpress function and everything displays perfectly.

The problem arises when I insert this string variable in the wordpress function directly, it fails.

Anybody have any ideas?

Code below:

```
<?php 
$faux_array = array();
$faux_array_all;

if($five_loans != ''): 
    $faux_array[] = "781";
endif; 
if($logbook_loans != ''): 
    $faux_array[] = "797";
endif;
if($easy_money != ''): 
    $faux_array[] = "803";
endif;

foreach($faux_array as $faux_array_value): 
    $faux_array_all .= $faux_array_value . ',';
endforeach;

echo $faux_array_all;

$args = array
(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'lender',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post__in' => array($faux_array_all)
);
?>
```

Comment: Post some code and we might be able to help.

Comment: how many parameters does your wp function take?

Comment: it would also be helpful if you post the error you're getting (if any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmh for one, you can avoid the loop with just:

```
$faux_array_all = implode(',', $faux_array);
```

which would also solve the trailing comma proble.m.

On the other hand, you pass an array to `post__in` that only contains one element (the string). I think what you really want is

```
'post__in' => $faux_array
```

as `$faux_array` is already an array with IDs.
Read about [**Post & Page Parameters**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Post_.26_Page_Parameters), there you can see that you need to pass an **array of post IDs** to the function, not an array with *one* string value:

> - 'post__in' => array(5,12,2,14,7) - inclusion, lets you specify the post IDs to retrieve

Answer (score 1):

```
'post__in' => $faux_array
```

Try this, and if it doesn't work post the code that you manually make to work please.

Edited. Check it now.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same result as mine. It only putputs one result. This works: 'post__in' => array(781,797,)

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim off the trailing comma

```
foreach($faux_array as $faux_array_value): 
    $faux_array_all .= $faux_array_value . ',';
endforeach;
if (substr($faux_array_all)-1,1) == ",") {
$faux_array_all = substr($faux_array_all,0,-1);
}
```

Comment: Still works without it and not the original problem but thanks for replying.